# Getting 10 Mbps on a 100 Mbps Connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router

I have two machines at home.  One is getting a full 100 Mbps when next to my router according to Fast.com, however my gaming laptop, a Dell G5 5590, only gets 5-10 Mbps when sitting directly next to the router.

I have tried all I can think of so I am reaching out for help here.   I sincerely hope someone can help me as this is affecting my teleworking capabilities and I am now fully remote due to this virus situation.

All of my drivers are up to date, I have tried changing my IP4/IP6 DNS to Google's servers, I have nothing running in the background (my idle network usage is sitting at 0%).

This is what `ping 8.8.8.8 -t` looks like:

```
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=42ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=89ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=56
Request timed out.
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=56
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 312, Received = 307, Lost = 5 (1% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 13ms, Maximum = 864ms, Average = 74ms
```

Device Manager:

[image: Device Manager]

My relevant wireless services on this laptop are:

[image: Services]

Comment: 1-Is the one getting the full 100Mbps wired to router? 2-Is the troublesome (gaming) one wired? 3-can you bypass router & connect troublesome PC to modem to see if router or it's WiFi is issue? 4-What model is the router?

Comment: 1-Wireless also, it's a Mac though, 2 - No ethernet cable at the moment, going to try that tomorrow if I can 3- See #2, 4-It's an Apple router, no info on it, not under my control.  Could this be a Mac-to-Mac but not PC issue?  Thanks.

Comment: You can be TOO close to a router. Test again with your laptop 2 meters away from the router.

Comment: @Spiff The computer that is sitting literally 6 inches away from the router gets 100 MBps.  I've tried all over the house, most I get MAX is 10 MBps, usually less.  Note that computer is a Mac and the router is Apple.  I'm wondering if that is why.

Answer (score 1):

- Does the router have 2.4 and 5Ghz? Connect to 2.4Ghz and then 5Ghz same issue? Your latency should be down to 20 ms being that close.
- You could have overlapping frequencies from other routers, equipment that is also transmitting is similar frequency (baby monitors) even CFL bulbs. Basically could be RF noise. Try to change Wifi channel frequencies on router.
- Reboot router. Use WPA2 for security.
- Turn off Bluetooth.
- Run Malwarebyte, clean up any critters in your browser.
- Install a different browser Firefox, Chromium, Opera, Vidvaldi. Install Windows Updates.

Consider buying a $5 USB wifi card, they help a lot for troubleshooting.

- Uninstall all wifi drivers. Uninstall wifi network adapter in Device Manager and reboot. Windows will install drivers.
- Try turning off the firewall and see if that changes anything.
- What antivirus are you using?  Consider uninstalling it and use Windows Defender while you troubleshoot.

If all that fails, show output of

```
ipconfig /all
```

Comment: My problem is I don't control the router.  It's an older Apple router and the machines getting 100 MBps are all Macs.   I think I am going to buy a strong, beamforming, multi-antenna based router.  First I'm going to directly hook to ethernet to see if I get full bandwidth.  My machine is pristine-clean and I have tried turning off firewall to no avail.  Thanks.

Comment: This turned out to be the Apple router.  I replaced it with a new Netgear router and now get 100 MBps.  Easy answer!

Answer (score 0):

1-In devman right click Intel Wireless.. properties, one of the tabs (Advanced or Features?) will have a list of items on the left & you're looking for Duplex or Negotiation, those MAY be unique to wired Ethernet but maybe not. If they aren't  on Auto try that settings, then maybe switch to 100/1000Mbps (or 1Gbps however noted).
2-I see virtual box network adapter, you aren't telling us the speed of a virtual machine in virtual box right? Those are separate speeds/settings. If possible I'd actually try to uninstall that adapter and/or virtual box for a test. I had a network issue at work & it was related to another VM software Hyper-V
3-Do you have another Windows laptop to try or even a phone JUST to isolate if it is something on your laptop vs maybe Apple router hating Windows that you can't control
4-Download & run a live Linux distribution from CD or USB drive. I like Ultimate Boot CD (for diagnostics) which has a live Linux I forget name of right now. Basically you're seeing if it's something in Windows causing your issue, that way you can confirm your laptop hardware can do the 100Mbps

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the Apple router.

The Mac machine was able to get 100 MBps with that router but my PC was not.

I replaced the Apple router with a new Netgear router and now all machines get 100 MBps.